# Matlab extractHOG function

Tags: matlab

After taking the HOG of a whole image, and taking the HOG of a 32x32 section, comparing the same location from the whole image HOG and the 32x32 HOG they are not the same. Is there a way to set the parameters; so, I can make the two HOGs equal?

Answer (score 0):

To make the HOG feature length same for different images with different sizes, you need to resize them to the same size first. Resize them to `32x32`, for your example.

Comment: Here is example:
Let's say I have image of size 500 by 500 pixels and I am interested only in a specific area of size 32 by 32 pixels and I want to compute the HOGs for hes 32 by 32 pixels area.
When I foloow two methods I get two different results:
- Method 1: I compute the HOG for the whole 500 by 500 pixels image and I crop the HOGs corresponding to that 32 by 32 area.
- Method 2: I crop the 32 by 32 image and compute the HOGs for it.
The two results are different.

Comment: @hisho The results should be different as they have different surrounding pixels. For the method 1, the surrounding pixels are coming from the original pixels, while in method 2, it depends how HOG pads its surroundings.

Comment: I agree with what you said but that should affect only the HOG values at the borders. HOGs values in the middle should be the same.
My understanding of how the HOG is computed; each block processed independently. And only blocks around borders should be affected with any padding.